Generate a random background color in javascript
Am new to JavaScript, I have this code where am trying to generate a random background color, which actually worked but the color title is not in alignment

   const color = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
function flip() {

    container.style.backgroundColor = color[getRandomColor()];

    header.textContent = color[getRandomColor()];

}

function getRandomColor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);

    }

}


I have tried it without the for loop and nothing worked again

"but the color title is not in alignment" - of course it isn't, because you are calling your function that determines a random color, twice - and since its result is random, the cases in which two consecutive calls will get you the same value, will be rare. You need to call getRandomColor once and store the result in a variable, and then use that variable in those two places.

Btw., that for loop makes no sense. The return statement will exit the whole function on the first loop iteration already.

Your example code also isn't in alignment.

Since your getRandomColor function only returns a single index, the for loop is not needed anyway. But calling the function once, save the returned index and pass the saved index to both: color[index]

That's the thing about generating a random number... It's random.  So it might not be the same number twice in a row.
Every time you call getRandomColor() it returns a random number.  (Not a random color, as its name suggests.)  And you call it twice:
container.style.backgroundColor = color[getRandomColor()];

header.textContent = color[getRandomColor()];

Given the length of your array, there's only a 25% chance that these two function calls will result in the same index being chosen in that array.
If you just want one random number, call the function once and use the resulting value twice:
const randomIndex = getRandomColor();

container.style.backgroundColor = color[randomIndex];

header.textContent = color[randomIndex];


As an aside...

I have tried it without the for loop and nothing worked again

Your for loop isn't doing anything meaningful, as you've guaranteed that it will only ever iterate once by returning from that iteration.  You may as well remove it:
function getRandomColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
}


Thank you very much . The problem is solved with your assistance

first save the value of getRandomColor() into a variable then you can use the same value on both.

    const color = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];
    let header = document.getElementById("header");
    let container = document.getElementById("container");

    function getRandomColor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
        }
    }

    function flip() {
        let randomColor = getRandomColor();
        container.style.backgroundColor = color[randomColor];

        header.textContent = color[randomColor];

    }



Define a variable and store the random index in that variable
const color = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
function flip() {
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
    container.style.backgroundColor = color[randomColor];
    header.textContent = color[randomColor];
}

